# Spark HbaseRDD giving Exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-spark

I am trying to read form Hbase using following code

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> pairRdd = ctx
        .newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
                ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class).cache().cache();

System.out.println(pairRdd.count());
```

But getting exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

Find below code

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkSQL");
sparkConf.set("spark.master","spark://192.168.50.247:7077");
```

/*   String [] stjars={"/home/BreakDown/SparkDemo2/target/SparkDemo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"};
    sparkConf.setJars(stjars);*/
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaSQLContext sqlCtx = new JavaSQLContext(ctx);

```
Configuration conf= HBaseConfiguration.create();
;
conf.set("hbase.master","192.168.50.73:60000");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","192.168.50.73");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
conf.set("zookeeper.session.timeout","6000");
conf.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry","1");


conf.set("hbase.mapreduce.inputtable","employee11");
```

Any pointer will be of great help

Spark version 1.1.1 hadoop 2 
hadoop  2.2.0
Hbase 0.98.8-hadoop2

PFB Stack Trace
14/12/17 21:18:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/12/17 21:18:46 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://192.168.50.247:7077...
14/12/17 21:18:46 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
14/12/17 21:18:46 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20141217211846-0035
   14/12/17 21:18:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.50.253, ANY, 1256 bytes)
14/12/17 21:18:47 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager 192.168.50.253:41717 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.50.253, 41717, 0)
14/12/17 21:18:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.50.253): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
        java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2420)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1380)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:160)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace from the error? Post it in the question.

Comment: Please find below stack trace

Comment: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.50.253): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
        java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2420)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1380)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)

Comment: org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:160)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: Post it in the original question.